# AJAX | jQuery | Success block is not calling | AEM

Tags: javascript, jquery, aem

My success block of Ajax call is not getting called. I attaching my code here, can you help in that.
JS Code:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form_table_action').submit(function() {
      var userName = document.getElementById("username").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/bin/servlet/loginData',
            data: {
                    'username': userName,
                    'password': password,
                },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Login success');
                window.location = "http://localhost:4502/content/AEMTraining/en/loginsuccesspage.html?wcmmode=disabled";
            },
            error: function(jqXHR) {
                console.log('Error while login');
            },
            dataType: 'html'
        });
    });
```

});

My Java Code which is calling from ajax while signin process.

```
@Component(service= Servlet.class,
    property={
            Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION + "=Login Servlet",
            "sling.servlet.methods=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_POST,
            "sling.servlet.paths="+ "/bin/servlet/loginData"
    })
```

public class LoginServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

```
/**
 * doPost method
 * @param request
 * @param response
 * @throws IOException
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String userName = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String outputMsg = null;
    if((userName.equals("")) || (password.equals(""))){
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        outputMsg = "User name or password field can not my empty";
}
else {
        ResourceResolver resourceResolver=request.getResourceResolver();
        UserAuthentication authentication = new UserAuthentication();
        if (authentication.verifyUser(userName,password,resourceResolver)){
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            outputMsg = "Welcome ! You have successfully login";
        }
        else {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            outputMsg = "User name or password is wrong.";
        }
}
    response.getWriter().write(outputMsg);
}
```

So, i am able to login and returning message (success message) is printing on my page but whatever i am writing in success block of Ajax..that is not calling.

Comment: What jquery version are you using? In jquery 3, `success()`, `error` callbacks are removed.

Comment: What is the status code of your ajax response ?

Comment: jquery version: 3.4.1 @palash, so how can i proceed with that..as i have to redirect end user to landing page..pls help

Comment: ajax response is 200 @ BadPiggie

Answer (score 1):

Outtake from the jquery upgrade guide:

*The jqXHR object returned from jQuery.ajax() is a jQuery Deferred and has historically had three extra methods with names matching the arguments object of success, error, and complete. This often confused people who did not realize that the returned object should be treated like a Deferred. As of jQuery 3.0 these methods have been removed. **As replacements, use the Deferred standard methods of done, fail, and always, or use the new then and catch methods for Promises/A+ compliance**.*

So you can choose to either use the same coding style and "done" and "fail", or you would like to use a promise instead with "then" and "catch".

Source:

https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-special-case-deferred-methods-removed-from-jquery-ajax